# creating dynamic link and sending html content with text to mail via django

Tags: python, html

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
def mail_fun(confirmation_id):

  subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'manikandanv3131@gmail.com', 'mani@ithoughtz.com'
  text_content = 'This is an important message.'

  html_content = """<a style="display: block;position: relative;background-color:    
  #2B7ABD;width: 144px;height: 30px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color:   
  white;font-size: 14px;top: 49px;border-radius: 4px;margin-left: 178px;" 
  href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm_mail/?confirmation_id=" + confirmation_id ><span 
  style="display:block;position: relative;top: 8px;">Confirm Email adress</span></a>
  """
  msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
  msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
  msg.send()

mail_fun('1234567890')
```

Problem here is, text content not is not displaying in the mail and the dynamic link in the code is also not working. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation will not work inside strings, you need to set up your strings correctly. In fact, you should actually be using templates for this, rather than having HTML inside your view.

Create a template for your email, save it under the `templates` directory of any application that is in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Email</title>
</head>
<style>
   div.link {
       display: 'block';
       position: 'relative';
       background-color: '#2B7ABD';
       width: 144px;
       height: 30px;
       text-align: center;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: white;
       font-size: 14px;
       margin-top: 49px;
       border-radius: 4px;
       margin-left: 178px;
   }
</style>
<body>
<div class="link"> 
  <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm_mail/?confirmation_id={{ id }}">Confirm Email adress</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In your view code:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

def send_email(id=None,
               subject='hello',
               from_email='manikandanv3131@gmail.com',
               to='mani@ithoughtz.com'):

    text_content = 'This is an important message.'
    html_content = render_to_string('html_email.html', {'id': id})
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

Keep in mind that if a mail client shows the HTML part, it will not show the alternative plain text part. You would have to view the source of the email to see both parts.

If this is something you will be doing often, you can use [`django-templated-email`](https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email) which offers more flexibility.